# Devise 3.4.1 doesn't validate a name with regex

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, devise, rubygems

After upgrade from `devise 2.3` to `devise 3.4.1` I can't register because devise doesn't want to push validation on the `name` with `p{L}` in regex.

This is my validation:

(regex should be valid when there is `name surname` or `name` and if it has special chars like `ą` `ę` `ó`)

```
validates :name, format: {
  with: /\A(\p{L}|\p{L}+\s+\p{L})+\z/,
  message: "some text here."
}, presence: true
```

Does anyone have similar case? Or I just have bad regex?

Comment: From my understanding your regex is matching a single unicode character belonging to the category "Letters". This will match any letter in any language. Can you provide examples of what should be valid and what should not be valid? OR are you saying that the validation fails no matter what? Are you getting errors?

Comment: Thanks for answer. This validation return error no matter what, but should valid e.g. "Steve Jabłoński" or "Steve".